# issue connecting DB2 database through python IBM_DB api

Tags: python, api, db2

I'm trying to connect to a database using ibm_db api with python but its throwing this error:

> SystemError:  returned NULL without setting
>   an error

I've used the same exact script on another machine and it works fine. So it seems like some issue with this machine. I'm using python 3.7 on this machine and python 3.6 on the other one.

Here is the code:

```
from ibm_db import connect
connection = connect('DATABASE=DB2test;'
                 'HOSTNAME=localhost;'
                 'PORT=50000;'
                 'PROTOCOL=TCPIP;'
                 'UID=etl;'
                 'PWD=123!@123ETLLET;', '', '')
```

By the way, I'm able to connect the same database using DBeaver.

Comment: You have a working machine and a failing machine. You found one difference (Python version). There may be other differences, which you must find out, because only you have all the information. Check privileges, permissions, bitness, operating-systems, versions of ibm_db and the Db2 client. Your question is not about programming , your question is about configuration. Dbeaver does not use CLI, it uses jdbc. Python ibm_db uses CLI. Different drivers.

Comment: You might get more help via the github issues page for python ibm_db. I see that another user had a similar issue (resolved by reinstall/upgrade of Windows). See https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/issues/308  . Stackoverflow might be the wrong place for this type of question.

Comment: Ive raised an issue on the github.
Also I found out there was some privileges issue, if I run my python script as administrator then it connects, but Im not required to do that from the other machine

Comment: Consider doing your own debugging to find the ACL difference(s) between working and failing runs. Get the sysinternals Process Monitor , and compare the access-denied errors from the smallest testcase, between the admin-run and nonadmin-run.